# SKAction to follow Circle CGPathRef in clockwise direction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

My SKSpriteNode follows this path in a counterclockwise direction, how do i make it so it follows the path in a **clockwise** direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
    CGPathRef circle = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,50,50), NULL);

    SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:circle asOffset:YES orientToPath:YES duration:5.0];

    SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];

    [player2 runAction:forever];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect()`, use `CGPathCreateMutable()` and `CGPathAddArc()` to create the circle path and use the `clockwise` parameter to control
the direction.

Untested code:

```
CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, 25, 25, 25, 0, 2*M_PI, true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(circle);
```

Comment: @user1216855: See updated answer, I hope that it works!

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have run into a problem though trying to use this in a SKAction repeating forever.  After the initial path is completed, the SKSpriteNode's position gets altered, moving up/right a few pixels each iteration.  Any ideas?

Comment: @DerekH: Sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

From Martin's answer a few changes cause the object to start and end at the same place:

In Objective C

```
CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, -25, 0, 25, 0, 2*M_PI, true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(circle);
```

In swift

```
let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, -25, 0, 25, 0, CGFloat(2.0 * M_PI), true)
CGPathCloseSubpath(path)
```