# How to followPath: in clockwise direction for rectangular shape path?

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction, cgpathref

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746843/skaction-to-follow-circle-cgpathref-in-clockwise-direction) on how to use SKAction to follow Circle CGPathRef in clockwise direction.

What about rectangular path? The default one will be in counter-clockwise fashion:

```
CGPathRef square =     CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(pathOriginX,pathOriginY,pathWidthX,pathHeightY), NULL);
SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:square asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:completeOnePathDuration];
```

Tried changing the end points but the result is the same.

Comment: The answer says "Instead of CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(), use CGPathCreateMutable() and CGPathAddArc()", did you try using something else than CGPathCreateWithRect, like CGAddLineToPoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** run the action in reverse to follow the path in the opposite direction

```
    [sprite runAction:[followTrack reversedAction]];
```

**Long Answer:** the followPath SKAction follows the direction in which the path was built. If you want your sprite to move along a rectangle path in a clockwise or counter-clockwise direction, then build the path accordingly. Alternatively, you can use the reverseAction method to follow a path in the opposite direction than it was built. Here are examples of both methods.

```
    BOOL clockwise = YES;
    BOOL reversedActionMethod = NO;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame)/2-50,CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)/2-50, 100, 100);
    SKAction *followTrackCW = [SKAction followPath:[self clockwiseRectanglePathWithRect:rect] asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];
    SKAction *followTrackCCW = [SKAction followPath:[self counterClockwiseRectanglePathWithRect:rect] asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:5];

    if (!reversedActionMethod) {
        if (clockwise) {
            [sprite runAction:followTrackCW];
        }
        else {
            [sprite runAction:followTrackCCW];
        }
    }
    else {
        if (clockwise) {
            [sprite runAction:[followTrackCCW reversedAction]];
        }
        else {
            [sprite runAction: followTrackCCW];
        }
    }
```

Build a rectangular-shaped path in clockwise order in scene coordinates (CCW in view coordinates)

```
- (CGPathRef) clockwiseRectanglePathWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat x = rect.origin.x;
    CGFloat y = rect.origin.y;
    CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
    CGFloat height = rect.size.width;

    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
    [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(x, y)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(x, y+height)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(x+width, y+height)];
    [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(x+width, y)];
    [bezierPath closePath];
    return bezierPath.CGPath;
}
```

Use built-in method to construct a rectangular-shaped path in counter-clockwise order in scene coordinates (and CW in view coordinates).

```
- (CGPathRef) counterClockwiseRectanglePathWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
    return bezierPath.CGPath;
}
```

Comment: Got it! thank you for taking the effort to provide the short and long answer :D